# Extract text with random numbers inside using C#

Tags: c#, string, extract

In C#, if I have a long string that will always contains somewhere a format such as W##S##Q## where # can be any number, how can I get that sequence of W##S##Q## extracted from the string. Bare in mind that the string may have more before or after but I am only interested in that sequence.

Regards.

Comment: The method you are looking for is called Regular Expression Matching or regex for short. Should be able to do exactly what you need.

Comment: [How to: Search Strings Using Regular Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wobbles comment is correct, a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) such as `@"W\d{2}S\d{2}Q\d{2}"` will do what you need. `\d` matches any any decimal digit and the `{2}` afterwards tells it to match exactly twice.

[This fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XFKfOc) gives an example of how you would extract the string you want from a longer string.

Answer (score 1):

Wobbles is right, Regular Expressions are the best way to do it generally. For your specific example, if you know in advance that the W,S,Q portions are always going to be in the same place you could use:

```
        string testString = "WSomethingW01S02Q03SomethingElse";
        bool TheRightString = false;

        string WNumString = string.Empty;
        string SNumString = string.Empty;
        string QNumString = string.Empty;

        int StartPosition = 0;
        do
        {
            StartPosition = testString.IndexOf('W', StartPosition);
            WNumString = testString.Substring(StartPosition, 3);
            SNumString = testString.Substring(StartPosition + 3, 3);
            QNumString = testString.Substring(StartPosition + 6, 3);

            StartPosition += 1;

            if (SNumString.StartsWith("S") && QNumString.StartsWith("Q"))
                TheRightString = true;

        } while (TheRightString == false);

        Console.WriteLine(WNumString + SNumString + QNumString);
        Console.ReadKey();
```